# Webmock: how to fake a gzipped response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stub, braintree, webmock

I don't have much experience with stubbing and am having issues with requests to [Braintree](http://braintreepayments.com/) using [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and [braintree-rails](https://github.com/lyang/braintree-rails).

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(ConnectionHelper)

  config.before(:each) do
    stub_request(:post, /.*braintree.*/).
    with(braintree_hash).to_return(gzipped_response)
  end
end
```

spec/support/connection_helper.rb

```
def gzipped_response
  {
    status: 200,
    body: "\u001F\x8B\b\0:\x87GU\0\u0003\u0003\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    headers: {}
  } 
end

def braintree_hash
  { :body => /.*/,
    :headers => {'Accept'=>'application/xml', 'Content-Type'=>'application/xml',
    'User-Agent'=>'Braintree Ruby Gem 2.42.0 (braintree-rails-1.4.0)',
    'X-Apiversion'=>'4'}
  }
end
```

Rspec error:

```
2) Content: when ordering content show page has relevant information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Order"
     Braintree::UnexpectedError:
       expected a gzipped response
     # ./app/classes/payment.rb:13:in `generate_token'
     # ./app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:44:in `pay'
     # ./spec/features/content_spec.rb:251:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm trying to test the page, not the payments themselves, however when rendering the page a token needs to be retrieved first and so I'm getting this error.

How would I go about faking a gzipped response, or alternatively skip anything to do with Braintree requests in my tests?

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
def pay
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @client_token = Payment.new(current_user).generate_token
end
```

app/classes/payment.rb

```
class Payment    
  def initialize(customer)
    @customer = customer
    @customer_id = @customer.id
  end

  def generate_token
    Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: @customer_id)
  end   
end
```

Comment: Could you add `PostsController#pay`?

Comment: @papirtiger I've added the code for the `controller`, however there are other `Payment` methods I will use here and there like `create_customer` and `customer_subscription` which will probably throw the same error due to the `gzipped response`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have any questions specifically about our API and client libraries, you can always [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Your stubbed response body needs to be gzipped. You can create an empty gzipped string like this:

```
irb(main):010:0> require 'stringio' 
=> false
irb(main):011:0> require 'zlib'
=> false
irb(main):012:0> Zlib::GzipWriter.new(StringIO.new("w")).close.string
=> "\u001F\x8B\b\0:\x87GU\0\u0003\u0003\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

So try this for your `status_ok` method:

```
def status_ok
  {
    status: 200,
    body: "\u001F\x8B\b\0:\x87GU\0\u0003\u0003\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    headers: {"Content-Encoding" => "gzip"}
  } 
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've tried with the code above but still getting the same error, updating my question now.

Comment: @mind.blank My mistake. I've updated my answer; you also need to set a content-encoding header.

Comment: @mind.blank If you're looking to skip generating a client token for your controller specs, why not stub `Braintree::ClientToken.generate`?